# How can I get locations of model from 2D view with Autodesk Forge API?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I can get locations with bounding box in the 3D view, but can not get right locations in the 2D view.

Code to get bounding box is following.

After getting bounding box, I calculate and get center point of the box.
When I use this code for the 2D view which is imported from Revit, I get a wrong value.

What is the right way to get locations of 2D object?

```
static getWorldBoundingBox(model, dbId) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      var fragIds = await ViewerToolkit.getFragIds(model, dbId);
      if (!fragIds.length) {
        return reject('No geometry, invalid dbId?');
      }
      var fragList = model.getFragmentList();
      var fragbBox = new THREE.Box3();
      var nodebBox = new THREE.Box3();
      fragIds.forEach(function(fragId) {
        fragList.getWorldBounds(fragId, fragbBox);
        nodebBox.union(fragbBox);
      });
      return resolve(nodebBox);
    } catch (ex) {
      return reject(ex);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you refer to the source code of `viewer.impl.fitToView()` there’s a couple of functions it uses to calculate the bounding boxes, here’s some of the code:

```
function getObjectBound2D(viewer, objectId) {
var model = viewer.model;
// This doesn't guarantee that an object tree will be created but it will be pretty likely
var bounds, bc, i;
if (model.is2d()) {
    bounds = new THREE.Box3();
    // move this next one up into the calling method
    bc = new avp.BoundsCallback(bounds);

    var dbId2fragId = model.getData().fragments.dbId2fragId;

    var fragIds = dbId2fragId[objectId];
    // fragId is either a single vertex buffer or an array of vertex buffers
    if (Array.isArray(fragIds)) {
        for (var j = 0; j < fragIds.length; j++) {
            // go through each vertex buffer, looking for the object id
            find2DBounds(model, fragIds[j], objectId, bc);
        }
    } else if (typeof fragIds === 'number') {
        // go through the specific vertex buffer, looking for the object id
        find2DBounds(model, fragIds, objectId, bc);
    }

    // should have some real box at this point; check
    if (!bounds.empty()) {
        return bounds;
    }
}

function find2DBounds(model, fragId, dbId, bc) {
    var mesh = model.getFragmentList().getVizmesh(fragId);
    var vbr = new avp.VertexBufferReader(mesh.geometry);
    vbr.enumGeomsForObject(dbId, bc);
}

function find2DLayerBounds(model, fragId, bc) {
    var mesh = model.getFragmentList().getVizmesh(fragId);
    var vbr = new avp.VertexBufferReader(mesh.geometry);
    var visibleLayerIds = that.getVisibleLayerIds();
    vbr.enumGeomsForVisibleLayer(visibleLayerIds, bc);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for relying. I got a right position of the object!